Switching 600 V, 5 A with >100 megohm isolation
On our robot, we have several 1.5 kW DC motors (either <350 Vdc @ 5 A max, or <650 Vdc @ 3 A max : the PCB I'm designing should accept both options). The command logic is embedded into the motors (isolated logic voltage and communication, which is outside the scope of this question), so no PWM to be done one the DC supply. The speed is controlled through the communication.
NB : the motors have an extra wire for protective earth (connected to the chassis of the motors). Protective earth is isolated (> 2000 V isolation) from 0 Vdc and 600 Vdc.
I would like to add a switching mechanism for three purposes :

ensure there is no voltage on the motor connectors when speed is set to 0
switch off the motors in some emergency/fault conditions (like over-current, emergency stop, communication loss, ...)
disconnect the motor in case of detected earth leakage in the motor (i.e. current leakage between chassis and 0 Vdc or 600 Vdc).

The isolation is measured with a line monitor by applying a +/-50Vdc voltage for 2 seconds between protective earth and either 0 Vdc rail or 600 Vdc rail. Any measurement bellow 20 MΩ (ie leakage current > 2.5 µA) is considered abnormal.
So the isolation/withstanding requirements when off are :

0 Vdc rail : < 2.5 µA leakage between -50 V dc and +50 Vdc ; withstanding +700 Vdc
600 Vdc rail : <2.5 µA leakage between 600 V - 50 V dc and 600 + 50 Vdc ; withstanding 0 Vdc

A simple solution would be an elector-mechanical relay with two poles. The problem is that at those voltage ratings, they are HUGE. The smallest I found so far is G7L-2A-X-SI DC12 , which is 52.5 x 35.5 mm.
Without the line isolation measurements going outside the voltage rail, one MOSFET to switch each rail (with isolated driver for the high side) could do the job. But the inverse diode will be an issue when the relative voltage is negative.
Is there any solution more compact than using a big relay as the one I identified?
NB : if needed, one can assume that switching on is always performed at 0 A. For switching off, if "frequent" switching under load is allowed (let's say more than 104 times during lifetime) it's a plus ; but if needed, I can restrain it to real emergencies, and accept a lifetime of only 20 switching off under load.

You can easily build a bidirectional solid-state relay from anti-serial MOSFETs. The problem will be the drain-source leakage. Power MOSFETs don't switch off perfectly.

A relay is best: not only is the on/off ratio much higher*, it counts as physical separation between conductors.  Only a sufficiently high voltage surge can jump the gap; the standoff rating is typically many times the voltage type rating.  Very important for safety and isolation purposes, like here!  Even if you might not be making use of the surge rating, the isolation is unmatched.
*The ratio is basically determined by the semiconductor bandgap.  To the extent a relay could be considered a semiconductor (and this is a generous hand-wave at best..), its bandgap is basically the work function of the contacts.  Besides that, the "drift region" (insulating distance through material) is much higher -- albeit through a relatively conductive / easy-to-make-conductive substance, air.
We have the technology today, to make semiconductor switches of -- still not comparable to the gross specs of mechanical contacts, but adequate for functional and safety purposes, let's say.  The problem is, you literally need bigger than your 50 x 35mm box, stuffed to the brim with SiC or GaN semiconductors, to withstand both fault current and surge voltage.  Needless to say, that brick will cost hundreds of dollars, just for the parts within it; it's just not economical.  Feasible, yes; economical, no.
SiC of adequate voltage ratings are currently available (if restricted / via proprietary channels, NDAs, probably ITAR, etc.); GaN would be either off-the-shelf parts in cascode stacks, or a development process probably a decade or two in the future to make single-chip kV-class parts.
On a related topic, if anyone's ever thought about migrating to a DC grid -- similar ideas apply.  DC switching and conversion are absolutely feasible, even in the extreme surge environment that is direct lightning strike to above-ground distribution poles; it would be challenging to get more efficient than existing transformers though, and far more challenging to qualify for anywhere near the same reliability (pole transformers easily last half a century before replacement!).  Even just something as pedestrian as fusing becomes a nightmare on medium voltage DC!  Fusing might be reason enough alone to continue preferring an AC grid, besides all the other advantages (and fairly minor disadvantages) it comes with.
...I suppose that's not actually all that off-topic of a diversion, really.  I imagine your project is too late in design to consider an AC, perhaps three-phase, solution along the umbilical or between attachments (or, because of the choice of available attachments, impossible anyway), but it might be interesting to think about if one were doing an original from-scratch design.

Relay was indeed my first idea. It's just the size (and to a lower degree the cost) of such "high" voltage relays that made me think if there isn't an alternative. || Surge currents will be very limited : excepted for very short duration (capacitors), there is about 8 ohms resistance in the umbilical (ie 75A short circuit current), and the supply is current limited (30A) and with circuit breaker. Voltage surges also seem unlikely (good power supply and big capacitors : so far I never observed a voltage surge of more than 10V on the 320V version)

As for 3 phase for the umbilical, it was considered, but the motors are of the shelf devices not available for AC, and converting and regulating AC to DC necessitated too much space and generates too much heat to be easily manageable.
